# Including paged dataframes in rmarkdown output suppresses html class from the class.output chunk option

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I'd like to format my Rmarkdown files based on class. Along those lines, the chunk options `class.source` and `class.output` are extremely useful. However, I've noticed that if I have paged dataframe outputs, the `class.output` option doesn't show up in the html. I'm guessing this has to do with the unnamed javascript code associated with making paged dataframe outputs. I don't have enough JS coding under my belt to diagnose the issue, though.

Basically, I'm just wondering if anyone has ideas of how to address this issue without having to change any of the JS scripts in the header of Rmarkdown-generated html.

Here is a reprex to generate the issue:

````
    ---
    title: "Rmarkdown reprex"
    author: "Jason Mercer"
    output:
      html_document:
        df_print: paged
    ---

    ```{r setup, include=FALSE}
    knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
    ```

    ```{r, class.output="mtcars"}
    data("mtcars")
    head(mtcars)
    ```
````